# appending a 0 ns to pandas datetime object

Tags: pandas

I have a datetime object as follows:

```
pd.to_datetime('2022-06-01')
```

I want to append `00:00:00.000` to the object to get
`2022-06-01 00:00:00.000`
Any ideas how to achieve this?
Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

How about this?

```
pd.to_datetime('2022-06-01').strftime("%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S.%f")[:-3]
```

```
'2022-06-01 00:00:00.000'
```

Comment: Why? What does this do?

Comment: I'm sorry if I misunderstood your question. I guessed you wanna get `2022-06-01 00:00:00.000`.